# Auto Generate Reference if HTML field left blank using MYSQL count of foreign key

Tags: html, mysql, sql

I have a input field in a basic html form which the user can either add their own reference number, or they can leave this input blank.  However I want it so that if the user leaves the field blank that the sql will generate a reference number based on a count of a foreign key in my mysql table.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (`reference`,)
VALUES (CASE {$inputValue}
            WHEN '' THEN sum(case when `fk` CONTAINS {$inputFK} then 1 else 0 end)
            ELSE {$inputValue}
        END)
```

When I've run the above code I get '#1111 - Invalid use of group function'

Is there a better way of doing this, or is there a way of fixing the above code?

Comment: You can't use `values` in this way - it's a single row, what does `sum` refer to outside of the context of a `select`?? You'll need to write it *as* a `select.

Comment: your query is so not possible in a Insert, where should `fk` come from thin air?  but even when you put that in a select ot doesn't make sense

Comment: I still get the '#1111 - Invalid use of group function' using a select statement in SUM.  It seems to be an issue with selecting from the same table I'm doing the INSERT to @Stu

Comment: fk is the table column I want to count @nbk

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve with a clear example using sample data and expected results. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @Stu.  I think it's just not possible to INSERT a value based on a query of the table you are inserting into sadly.  But thanks for your input and sorry if I've wasted your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the commants already explained , you need some selects to run this query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE my_table (reference int, colum1 varchar(50) , fk varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO my_table (reference) 
> SELECT CASE `colum1`
>             WHEN '' THEN (SELECT  sum( `fk` = 'test' ) FROM my_table)
>             ELSE 1
>         END
>         FROM my_table
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM  my_table
> ```
>
> ```
> reference | colum1 | fk
> --------: | :----- | :-
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15ad054d36666e88e4eba679ebb01a07)*

Comment: Thank you, that did work.  Sorry to @Stu who did mention this already.  I did try using a SELECT statement before but got the same error without the SELECT, I probably should have posted both to avoid the down votes

Comment: Note: Instead of CASE `colum1` I did CASE '' i.e so it worked with my example